# Can I use a speed controller for a ceiling fan as an ESC for a brushless DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, control, motor-controller

[image: a ceiling fan speed controller]

I have a BLDC but don't have an ESC to control it, as an alternative can I use the speed controller of a ceiling fan to control it?

Comment: Typically ceiling fans use AC, and a controller for it will have a TRIAC to control it. TRIACs cant turn off while there is current constantly flowing through them (i.e. DC), so most likely you wont be able to use it to control a DC motor.

Answer (score 1):

No. A ceiling fan provides variable single-phase fixed frequency AC voltage. A brushless DC motor requires positive and negative timed pulses to two or three phase windings.